# JS/jQuery on function doesn't work after updating p:graphicImage

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have an image:

```
<p:graphicImage id="map" value="#{controller.image}" cache="false"/>
```

which I update via

```
<p:commandButton action="#{controller.redrawMap}" update=":myForm:map"/>
```

after the update the `map` doesn't respond to

```
$("#myForm\\:map").on("mousedown", function(event) {
    console.log("Test");
});
```

why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you bind an event on a component and this component gets updated it loses the event, so you have to re-bind that event.

***OR***

The best practice for this case is to bind the event on the main container, which *assumed* that it won't be updated, for example the form:

```
$('#myForm').on('mousedown','#myForm\\:map',function(){
    console.log("Test");
});
```

In this way the bind will remain even if you update the map.

Hope this helps.